# PowerShell Test-Path does not work for argument-parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

During my analysis why my script isn't working I could find some solutions that solves some basic parts (also with the help of Stackoverflow), but there is still an issue for which I cannot find a solution.

When I create a temp-directory-variable $PARAM_TEMP and check this with Test-Path everything is working fine (wether the directory exists or not). But on the next part, when I use the same technique for the arguments-parameter $PARAM_DESTINATION the statement-result is wrong (I already found the hint for adding single-quotes - after this, at least the scripts runs through without errors).
When I test my test-output in console in the Windows-Explorer, it finds the directory (thus it definitely exists)

here's the content of my script BeforeInstallationScript2.ps1:

```
#
# BeforeInstallationScript2.ps1
#
param(
        [Parameter(
                    Mandatory=$true,
                    Position=0,
                    HelpMessage='Path to targetDir')]
        [string] $PARAM_DESTINATION
)
"1st Argument: $PARAM_DESTINATION"

# create temporary directory if not exists
$PARAM_TEMP=$env:TEMP+"\MyApp"
"temporary Directory: $PARAM_TEMP"
if(!(Test-Path -Path "$PARAM_TEMP" )){
    "temp-dir does NOT exist and will be created"
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $PARAM_TEMP
} else {
    "temp-dir exist"
}

# create Timestamp-variable for saving configs  
$a = Get-Date
$DATETIME= "" + $a.Year + $a.Month + $a.Day +  $a.Hour + $a.Minute
"Timestamp: $DATETIME"

# if there exists already a myApp-Installation, copy config-files
"Parameter-Path=: $PARAM_DESTINATION"
"exists? = " + (Test-Path "'$PARAM_DESTINATION'" )
if((Test-Path -Path "'$PARAM_DESTINATION'" )) {
    "param-path exists"

    if((Test-Path -Path "'$PARAM_DESTINATION\configuration\MyApp.conf'" )) {
        "copy file to $PARAM_TEMP\$DATETIME-MyApp.conf"
        Copy-Item "$PARAM_DESTINATION\configuration\MyApp.conf" "$PARAM_TEMP\$DATETIME-MyApp.conf"
    }
} else {
    "not existing, no files to copy/save"
}
```

I this script in powershell get the output as follows:

```
PS X:\MyApp-Setup> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Version 2.0 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\BeforeInstallationScript2.ps1" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer"
1st Argument: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
temporary Directory: C:\Users\ixmid\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApp
temp-dir does NOT exist and will be created


    Verzeichnis: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        16.11.2016     11:01            MyApp
Timestamp: 20161116111
Parameter-Path=: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
exists? = False
not existing, no files to copy/save


PS X:\MyApp-Setup>
```

As you can see, first Test-Path works fine, and creates the missing directory. But at the second part it doesn't work fine.
Any suggestions, why the second (and third) Test-Path-statements are working wrong?

For completion: second output of executing the script (when MyApp-directory now exists) looks as follows:

```
1st Argument: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
temporary Directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApp
temp-dir exist
Timestamp: 201611161113
Parameter-Path=: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
exists? = False
not existing, no files to copy/save
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use both `"` quotes and `'` quotes. If you want variables, `$PARAM_DESTINATION` in this case, to expand you need to use double quotes only. So: `"$PARAM_DESTINATION"`.

Read up more on double and single quotes
http://windowsitpro.com/blog/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-powershell-whats-difference

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried it already with double-quotes without single-quotes ... anyway it is working now, thank you